# Set the dotnet runtime in wine for pythonnet

Tags: python, wine, python.net, .net-runtime

I am running wine in docker.
Inside this container pytest is used and a library imports [pythonnet 3.0.3](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet)

When running a test, the following error comes up:

```
   RuntimeError: Failed to create a default .NET runtime, which would
                       have been "netfx" on this system. Either install a
                       compatible runtime or configure it explicitly via
                       `set_runtime` or the `PYTHONNET_*` environment variables

                       (see set_runtime_from_env).
```

This seemed ta have changed in the last 5 months, it worked this summer and without changes to my dockerfile or the python module versions it wont run now.

```
ARG PY_VERSION=3.11

# See: https://github.com/webcomics/pywine/blob/main/Dockerfile
FROM docker.io/tobix/pywine:$PY_VERSION

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install wget

RUN wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks && \
     chmod +x winetricks && \
     mv winetricks /usr/local/bin

RUN winetricks -q dotnet45

WORKDIR /app

ADD ./requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN wine python --version
RUN wine python -m pip install pytest pytest-cov
RUN wine python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I then installed winetricks and `winetricks dotnet40` (also did `dotnet48`) so the framework is in
*/opt/winetricks/drive_c/windows/Microsoft.NET/Runtime/v4.0.30319/*

And I set `PYTHONNET_RUNTIME` to multiple different values (`corefx,coreclr,dotnet40` also the path and subpaths to where dotnet is installed

Hoewever, nothing worked.

When setting the env vairable, the error changes slightly:

```
RuntimeError: Failed to create a .NET runtime (dotnet40) using the
                   parameters {}.
```

I have read all google links I could find, asked ChatGPT/Bing with all the details and they basically gave me the Google links back.

It is suggested to set it to `coreclr` - however I do not have .Net Core installed on wine

**So my questions are:**

- what are the runtimes called? (like 'coreclr') - what do I have to put in there as a parameter/string
- how do I get pythonnet running in wine?

Comment: The .NET Framework runtime is called `netfx` here. See https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/blob/eef67db7ff800c550b509fd4aa0eeedd86647801/pythonnet/__init__.py#L15